# Telerik report fit into a page

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am using telerik reports. Some of my reports are large sized. When printing these reports not fit into default page size. I need to fit it into page by default. How can I implement this? Pls reply

Answer (score 0):

Each report has a defined size in its definition which you can change and the same goes for page margins. You should also have in mind that each printer has hardware margins which is not possible to override. With that taken into account, you should be able to set an appropriate size that prints correctly. If still in dilema, elaborate on the report size, its pagesettings and the printer and paper format you're trying to print to.